# Valgrind on OS X Mavericks

Tags: c, macos, valgrind

My programming course requires me to check for memory leaks which I have done until now on Linux using Valgrind.

I would like to do so now on my Mac running the latest OS X Mavericks 10.9.2.

There are few threads available on running Valgrind on OS X so I was wondering if anyone had a solution for this. Is there any yet? All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid, however, that this question is a little bit off-topic here. StackOverflow is for programming questions, this is not a programming question. Don't be surprised if it's closed.

Comment: It's programming-related, in that valgrind is a tool used while programming.  That said, I've never had much luck running valgrind under OS/X; it might be easier to create (or acquire) a Linux VM and run valgrind there instead.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tree/master/Library)?

```
brew install valgrind
```

Comment: This way works to install it, but doesn't actually run properly as far as I can tell.

Comment: It doesn't even install for me with homebrew. I get the same error as when I try the install manually, that the OS isn't supported.

Comment: You can install a more recent (but not most current) version via Homebrew with: brew install --HEAD valgrind